# Tableau Map Services cannot connect to openrailway.org

Tags: tableau-api, openstreetmap

Not sure if it is the trial version or the wrong link that I am using. However, I am simply trying to use openrailwaymap.org as my background map 
(Map  > Background Maps > Maps Services ... > Add ... > WMS Servers).

I used https://www.openrailwaymap.org/ for the URL but I am absolutely not sure how it's supposed to be.

What should be the right URL?

Thanks for your help

--- EDIT ---

Following this [tutorial](http://kb.tableau.com/articles/howto/creating-a-custom-map-connection), I created a .tms file and saved at the respective spot:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mapsource inline="false" version="8.1">
<connection class="OpenStreetMap" port="80" server="http://b.tiles.openrailwaymap.org" url-format="/standard/${z}/${x}/${y}.png" />
<layers>
<layer display-name="Base" name="base" show-ui="false" type="features" request-string="/" />
</layers>
</mapsource>
```

Yet when I select my custom background map I have a blank canvas ... I have found other users [reporting the same issue](https://blog.hwr-berlin.de/codeandstats/customizing-map-background-in-tableau/) but no reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know tableau. However OpenRailwayMap uses TMS (like most OSM maps) and not WMS.

The correct TMS URLs are:

```
https://a.tile.openrailwaymap.org/standard/${z}/${x}/${y}.png
https://b.tile.openrailwaymap.org/standard/${z}/${x}/${y}.png
https://c.tile.openrailwaymap.org/standard/${z}/${x}/${y}.png
```

Or just

```
https://{s}.tile.openrailwaymap.org/standard/${z}/${x}/${y}.png
```

`standard` can be replaced by `maxspeed` and `signals` to show the corresponding themes.

Make sure to respect the tile usage policy of OpenRailwayMap. I couldn't find any written policy but at least make sure not to bulk download their tiles.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Why did you paste 3x the same URL? Is ${z} , e.g.,a placeholder?

Comment: Sorry, I fixed my answer. See the updated URLs. `{s}` is a placeholder for `a`, `b`, `c`.